# Verify checksum of IP header and TCP header

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, ip

I am looking for the code in linux kernel that verifies the checksum of TCP header and IP header for inbound packet. The packet supposes to be dropped if the checksum doesn't match.

I tried tcp_input.c and ip_input.c, also with global search. But I couldn't find any code that does this job. Can anyone tell me where is the code?  Thanks.

Comment: in tcp_input.c there is various checksum related stuff, look out for `'goto csum_error'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ip_fast_csum() which defined in net/checksum.h (for IP header), and tcp_checksum_complete_user() which defined in tcp_input.c (for TCP header).
Please be noticed that these functions are platform specific.